# How to check table UNLOGGED with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <tablename>
```

How can I first check if the desired table is created `UNLOGGED`, and if not alter the table accordingly?

postgres 9.4

Comment: to the second part of the question, `alter table <tablename> set unlogged`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can check column `relpersistence` of table `pg_class`;

```
postgres=# select relpersistence, relname from pg_class where relname like 'foo%';
┌────────────────┬─────────┐
│ relpersistence │ relname │
╞════════════════╪═════════╡
│ p              │ foo     │
│ p              │ foo1    │
│ u              │ foo2    │
└────────────────┴─────────┘
(3 rows)
```

`foo2` is unlogged table.